# How to pass values from python to html checkboxs?

Tags: python, html, flask, checkbox

I am new to flask and html. How do I pass values from flask to html checkbox?
Like I have milk, chocolate, water in my flask. How do I send it to html check boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have list of values

just use for loop in HTML section

and use `<input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="box1" {{'checked="checked"' if box1 else ""}}/>`

Comment: is checked passing from flaks?

Comment: ohokay then how do I pass the values from flask to that condition?

Comment: you must be having list in view of flask

Comment: {% for galaxy in galaxies %}
           <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="galaxy" {{'checked="checked"' if galaxy else ""}}/>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: how do I get the names of next to the checkbox? should I use same condition with labels?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227367/discussion-between-noor-ahmed-natali-and-ram-dr).